# I'd like to know how to open unity app from website link(Android/iOS)

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon-pun

I am developing unity app for Android/iOS. This app is developed with Unity + Photon. And I am going to add social invitation to this app.Users can post invitation link to whatsapp channel or messenger.
If other users click this link, they can redirect to the app and join the room.
So what I want to implement is that:

1. Open unity app from web link
2. How to send this invitation link so that users can click and open unity app
   Thank you.

Kindly help me.
Tank you.

Comment: Question is too broad. Please break it down and also mention what you've tried so far.

Comment: What you are referring to / looking for is a ["deep link"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/deep-linking.html)